How can set action for edit and view the web form submission record?
I create a view page using the webform submission result. How can set the action for editing and view the particular submission result record?


You have to add the operations field to the table. If it doesn't exist you have to provide it from a custom module or check if the Webform Views Integration module provides it.

Use Webform Views Integration module to expose Webform submissions to Views.

